# How do I get my JPanels to change color in the right cyclical order?

Tags: java, swing

So I have seven panels of different colors that need to be rotated in order. My code is working well for the most part but the first and last panels always have same color. How do I fix this?

I have already checked that each of my panels have a different color upon start.

Code:

```
     public void run()
  {
     TimerTask colorAction = new TimerTask(){
       public void run()
   {                                   
           redPanel.setBackground(orangePanel.getBackground());           
           orangePanel.setBackground(yellowPanel.getBackground());
           yellowPanel.setBackground(greenPanel.getBackground());
           greenPanel.setBackground(bluePanel.getBackground());
           bluePanel.setBackground(indigoPanel.getBackground());
           indigoPanel.setBackground(violetPanel.getBackground());
           violetPanel.setBackground(redPanel.getBackground());                      
   }        
     }; 
    java.util.Timer utilTimer  = new java.util.Timer();
      utilTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(colorAction, START_AFTER, DELAY );                 
  }
```

Snapshot (before change):

[image]

Snapshot (after change)

[image]

Comment: Okay, first, don't use `java.util.Timer`, use `javax.swing.Timer`!

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's an assignment that emphasizes that we use java.util.Timer
But I'll take your advice

Comment: Then the assignment is wrong, as you are violating single thread requirements of Swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem, other then the fact that you are violating the single thread rules of Swing, is you are relying on a value from component whose background has already changed...

```
violetPanel.setBackground(redPanel.getBackground());
```

`redPanel`'s background is now set to `orangePanel` background by the time you call this.

Instead, first grab `redPanel`'s background color before you change anything, then apply it to `violetPanel`

```
Color redBackground = redPanel.getBackground();
redPanel.setBackground(orangePanel.getBackground());
//...
violetPanel.setBackground(redBackground);
```

Take a look (and get your teacher to do the same) at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...

If you MUST use a `java.util.Timer`, you should be wrapping your changes to UI in an `invokeLater` call, for example...

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Color redBackground = redPanel.getBackground();
        redPanel.setBackground(orangePanel.getBackground());
        //...
        violetPanel.setBackground(redBackground);  
    }
});
```